# grep returns No such file or directory in Script but works manually

Tags: grep

What i wanted was to make a little Script that makes a grep over files that successfully passed another grep.

Here is that i wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash -f

if (( $# != 3 ))
then
    echo "Usage: $0 <directory> <grep1> <grep2>"
    exit 1
fi

dir=$1
grep1=$2
grep2=$3

files=`grep -Ril "$grep1" $dir`

for file in $files; do
        grep -iH "$grep2" $file
done
```

so this works, in case the directory is a specific one.
But It doesnt work in the way i wanted to use it:

```
./grepIfSucceededGrep.sh /mnt/logs/\*/20130929/\* test1 test2
grep: /mnt/logs/*/20130929/*: No such file or directory
```

But when i enter the command manually it works perfectly. Must have to do something with the asterisk.

```
grep -Ril "segment1" /mnt/logs/*/20130929/*
/mnt/logs/1111/20130929/000033.00.log
/mnt/logs/1112/20130929/000033.00.log
/mnt/logs/1113/20130929/154852.00.log
/mnt/logs/1114/20130929/171227.00.log
```

Why?! :( just searched for 2 hours to get a workarround but had no fix for that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need a *script* to achieve what you need?  You can say:

```
find /path -type f -exec sh -c "grep -iq string1 {} && grep -iq string2 {} && echo {}" \;
```

This would list the files in `/path` and subdirectories that contain both `string1` and `string2`.

If you need to put it into a script so that you could pass parameters, say:

```
find $1 -type f -exec sh -c "grep -iq $2 {} && grep -iq $3 {} && echo {}" \;
```

within a file, say `myfind.sh` that could be invoked by saying `sh myfind.sh /my/path/to/search firststring secondstring`.

Comment: Hi,
This is not the information, why the bashscript doesn't work, but solves my problem.
One thing: at the moment, i only get the file names, is there a way to get the filename AND the line where "string2" is found?
Can you explain what that command does?

lg

Comment: If you need the lines where string2 is found, say `find /path -type f -exec sh -c "grep -iq string1 {} && grep -i string2 {}" \;`